# Why do you need to say 'something new', but not 'new something'?

Tags: adjective-phrases

Why you can't put 'new' in front of 'something' to use 'new' as adjective to describe 'something'?

Comment: Please include a sample sentence so that we can understand what you're asking more easily :D

Answer (score 2):

It is a minor difference. I know it in my mind, but I will try to explain the difference.

If you said:

> I am going to the dept. store to buy **something new**.

You haven't decided what it is yet, but it will be *new*. The emphasis is on "new". "something" is modifying "new".

> I am going to the dept. store to buy *a* **new something**.

In this example you are hedging on saying what you will buy. Maybe you know but just didn't want to tell anyone. It will be "new", but the emphasis is on "something".
Also an article is needed because "something" acts as a noun.

Answer (score 0):

*Some* is a quantifier, and quantifiers come before adjectives that come before nouns:

- *some/few/35 red/big/expensive cars/houses/flowers*

but only in the order `Quantifier + Adjective + Noun`. You can't say

- **red 35 cars*, **expensive some houses,* **big few flowers*

Thus, since *something* is made by combining a quantifier with a noun (*some + thing*), there simply isn't any room left between them for an adjective. Put a different way, *something* is not a noun that can be modified by a prenominal adjective; adjectives modifying it are phrases and must follow it.

Summary: You can say *some new thing* or *some thing (that is) new* or *something (that is) new*.